# What do I type into browser address to get to my Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have tried typing my email address into browser but it does not take me to my Gmail, it takes me to another of my Google accounts.  Too confusing with different logins for different Google things.  All I want to do now is to get to my emails.  Something must have gone wrong as I think all I used to do is type my address into browser and it logged me in.

Please help me as I need to check my mail and haven't been able to do so now for days.

Answer (score 3):

The following url will suffice (in chrome): **mail.google.com**

After that you will be either entering your Gmail account or asked to sign in (you will be re-directed automatically).

Use the [Account Chooser](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1691641) to add muliple google accounts. Lateron, you can swap between different accounts (Mail) and do that in different Google Apps.

Comment: [gmail.com](http://gmail.com) will also redirect just fine.

Comment: Clicking on the GMail tab on google.com will also work.